# I made a minesweeper game with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, minesweeper

I'm a total beginner who just started learning to code with the book "Head First Learn to Code". I've just finished the book and coded a minesweeper game with python3 on my mac. **I hope to get some advice on the game I made. If you feel like the code is too long to read, here are some specific questions I'd like to ask:**

1. What does this: flag = flag.resize((12, 12), Image.ANTIALIAS) actually do, why do I need to assign it a variable instead of just doing this: flag.resize((12, 12), Image.ANTIALIAS) as I'd do with other objects
2. Is there a better way to create a stopwatch? Mine is the function update_time.
3. Did I make any mistake regarding the conventions of python? Please point out some for me.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**
Here's my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random as rd
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import sys


    class GameGrid(Frame):     #the game
        def __init__(self, master, height, width, mines_count, player):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.grid(row=0)
            self.master = master
            if sys.platform == 'win32':     #checking os
                self.platform = 'windows'
            else:
                self.platform = 'macos'
            self.height = height     #storing height, width, mines_count, and player's name
            self.width = width
            self.mines_count = mines_count
            self.player_name = player
            self.play_time = 0     #initiating play_time and other values
            self.lost = False
            self.won = False
            self.notmine = height * width - mines_count     #calculate the number of tiles that are not mines
            flag = Image.open('flag.png')    #creating and storing flag and bomb images
            flag = flag.resize((12, 12), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            bomb = Image.open('bomb.png')
            bomb = bomb.resize((12, 12), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.flag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(flag)
            self.bomb = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bomb)
            
            grid_model = [[0]*width for item in [0]*height]     #creating a list to hold 1's and 0's
            while mines_count > 0:                              #1 is mine, 0 is normal
                randi = rd.randint(0, height-1)     #putting mines into the list by generating random coordinates
                randj = rd.randint(0, width-1)      #and storing mine in the corresponding place
                if grid_model[randi][randj] == 0:
                    grid_model[randi][randj] = 1
                    mines_count -= 1
            self.tiles = {}     #creating Tiles and storing them using dictionary
            for i in range(height):
                for j in range(width):   
                    if grid_model[i][j] == 1:
                        self.tiles[i, j] = Tile(self, i, j, True)
                    else:       
                        mine_neighbors = 0     #counting nearby mines if Tile in creation is not a mine
                        if i - 1 >= 0:
                            if grid_model[i-1][j] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if i - 1 >= 0 and j - 1 >= 0:
                            if grid_model[i-1][j-1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if i - 1 >= 0 and j + 1 < width:
                            if grid_model[i-1][j+1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if j - 1 >= 0:
                            if grid_model[i][j-1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if j + 1 < width:
                            if grid_model[i][j+1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if i + 1 < height:
                            if grid_model[i+1][j] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if i + 1 < height and j - 1 >= 0:
                            if grid_model[i+1][j-1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        if i + 1 < height and j + 1 < width:
                            if grid_model[i+1][j+1] == 1:
                                mine_neighbors += 1
                        
                        self.tiles[i, j] = Tile(self, i, j, False, mine_neighbors)
         
        def reveal_surroundings(self, i, j):     #reveal nearby tiles
            revealing = []
            width = self.width
            height = self.height

            
            if i - 1 >= 0:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i-1, j])
            if i - 1 >= 0 and j - 1 >= 0:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i-1, j-1])
            if i - 1 >= 0 and j + 1 < width:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i-1, j+1])
            if j - 1 >= 0:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i, j-1])
            if j + 1 < width:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i, j+1])
            if i + 1 < height:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i+1, j])
            if i + 1 < height and j - 1 >= 0:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i+1, j-1])
            if i + 1 < height and j + 1 < width:
                revealing.append(self.tiles[i+1, j+1])


            for tile in revealing:
                tile.reveal()


        def lose(self):     #show if lost, stop the clock
            global stp
            stp = True
            self.lost = True
            if self.platform == 'windows':
                for tile in self.tiles:
                    if self.tiles[tile].mine:
                        self.tiles[tile].config(bg='red')
            
            else:    
                for tile in self.tiles:
                    if self.tiles[tile].mine:
                        self.tiles[tile].config(image=self.bomb, padx=9, pady=4, bg='red')
                    self.tiles[tile].unbind('<Button-1>')
                    self.tiles[tile].unbind('<Button-2>')   
            messagebox.showerror(message='Boom, Game Over!!')
            self.score = ScoreBoard(self.master)
            
            
        def win(self):      #show if won, stop the clock, creating a window recording scores
            global mn, sc, stp
            stp = True
            self.won = True
            for tile in self.tiles:
                if self.tiles[tile].mine:
                    self.tiles[tile].config(image=self.bomb, padx=9, pady=4, bg='red')
                self.tiles[tile].unbind('<Button-1>')
                self.tiles[tile].unbind('<Button-2>')
            messagebox.showinfo(message='Congrats, You Survived ;)')
           
            play_time = str(m) + ' mins, ' + str(s) + ' secs'
            self.score = ScoreBoard(self.master, self.player_name, play_time)
                    

                    

    class ScoreBoard(Toplevel):     #for score recording
        def __init__(self, master, name=None, time=None):
            Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
            self.title('Hall of Fame')                   
            fin_text = ''
            
            if name != None:    #writing in the record if there is one
                self.board = open('ScoreBoard.txt', 'r')    #assigning the text inside ScoreBoard.txt to board_text
                board_text = ''                             #and writing it into ScoreBoard.txt
                for line in self.board:
                    board_text = board_text + line
                self.board = open('ScoreBoard.txt', 'w')
                self.record = name + ' ' + time 
                self.board.write(board_text + '\n' + self.record)
                
            self.board = open('ScoreBoard.txt', 'r') #reading text in ScoreBoard and put it on the window

            for line in self.board:
                fin_text = fin_text + line
            self.lbl = Label(self, text=fin_text)
            self.lbl.pack()
            self.geometry('300x300')
            self.board.close()
                
                
                
            
        
    class Tile(Label):      #the Tile
        def __init__(self, master, i, j, mine, mine_neighbors=None):
            Label.__init__(self, master, width=2, relief=RAISED)
            self.grid(row=i, column=j)
            self.game = master     #storing row, column, is mine or not, count of nearby mines
            self.mine = mine
            self.row = i
            self.col = j
            self.mine_neighbors = mine_neighbors
            self.revealed = False
            self.marked = False
            self.bind('<Button-1>', self.reveal)    #bind Tile: reveal(left click), mark(right click)
            self.bind('<Button-2>', self.mark)

        def reveal(self, event=None):       #revealing tile
            if self.mine:
                self.game.lose()
                return
            else:
                if not self.revealed:
                    self.revealed = True
                    self.mark()
                    self.unbind('<Button-1>')
                    self.unbind('<Button-2>')
                    if self.mine_neighbors == 0:    #if no nearby mines, reveal nearby tiles
                        self.config(text='', relief=SUNKEN, bg='lightgrey', image='', padx=1, pady=1)
                        self.game.reveal_surroundings(self.row, self.col)
                    else:
                        self.config(text=self.mine_neighbors, relief=SUNKEN, bg='lightgrey', image='', padx=1, pady=1)
                    self.game.notmine -= 1

                
                if self.game.notmine == 0:
                    self.game.win() 

        def mark(self,event=None):      #marking tile
            if self.game.platform == 'windows':
                if not self.marked:
                    self.config(text='*')
                    self.marked = True
                else:
                    self.config(text='')
                    self.marked = False
        
            else:
                if not self.marked:
                    self.config(image=self.game.flag, padx=9, pady=4)
                    self.marked = True
                else:
                    self.config(image='', padx=1, pady=1)
                    self.marked = False

                    
    stp = False     #used to stop the clock when lost or won


    def update_time():     #a stopwatch
        global m, s, timer, stp
        if stp != True:
            s = s + 1
            if s == 60:
                m = m + 1
                s = 0

            mn = str(m)     #making the clock look better by adding a 0 when the number
            sc = str(s)     #of second or minute is just one digit, e.g. 01, 06, 09..
            if len(sc) == 1 and len(mn) == 1:
                sc = '0' + sc
                mn = '0' + mn
                timer.config(text=mn+':'+sc)
            elif len(mn) == 1 and len(sc) != 1:
                mn = '0' + str(m)
                timer.config(text=mn+':'+str(s))
            elif len(sc) == 1 and len(mn) != 1:
                sc = '0' + sc
                timer.config(text=mn+':'+sc)
     
            timer.after(1000, update_time)


    def play(height, width, mines_count, player):       #initiating the game
        global s, m, timer
        m = 0
        s = -1

        time = str(m) + ':' + str(s)
        
        root = Tk()
        root.title('MineSweeper')
        root.resizable(False, False)

        timer = Label(root, text='%i:%i'%(m,s))     #creating stopwatch and update it every second
        timer.grid(row=1)
        update_time()
        
        game = GameGrid(root, height, width, mines_count, player)
        root.mainloop()
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':   
        play(10, 10, 10, 'Harley')
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well done. As a coder, stackoverflow (SO) is worth learning how to query and contribute questions. You also may if you have not already, learn how to use Github. That is the best place to show and share your code projects.

Comment: ok, will post this on codereview!

Comment: @Cam_Aust I just created a Github account the other day! was confused about what it is used for. Thanks for advising!

Comment: My pleasure.  It seems you are beginning on a big adventure into a large and diverse environment, to which this SO and Github are two key environments to read up and learn how to use and participate in.  Utube is your friend also here to learn more.